# How to make voice over reads only visible tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I implemented the voiceover for my app ,in message detail screen when i play the voiceover for whole screen it starts reading the cells which are not visible in the cell, i want to read only visible cells like iPhone default message app.

Comment: Without a specific app to look at it's hard to tell what's going on. Are you setting the `isHidden` property of the views in the cell to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are setting the isHidden flag on your views and that is not preventing them from being read via VoiceOver, you might try setting `isAccessibilityElement=false` for the hidden items, or using `accessibilityElementsHidden`.

(I haven't used `accessibilityElementsHidden` before, but based on the description it sounds like it turns off accessibility (VoiceOver) for the subviews of a vieww.)

Comment: For an individual element on the screen which needs to be skipped by the VoiceOver, `isAccessibilityElement = false` is enough. To hide all the elements inside a parent element, for ex, all the labels, buttons, etc. inside a UIView, then it is needed to assign `accessibilityElementsHidden = true` for the UIView only.

Comment: @Starsky that's what I figured. The OP will need to toggle isHidden and isAccessibilityElement together in order make his views stop being spoken by VoiceOver when they are hidden and re-enable speaking them when VoiceOver is on.

Comment: In the app that I work on, I don't hide the views which I don't want the VoiceOver to go over. Since VoiceOver is used for blind people, I figured it doesn't really matter if there are 5 elements on the screen, but only 3 need to be voiced. Hiding views will introduce unnecessary code.

Comment: @Starsky, I meant if the OP wants to sometimes hide fields and sometimes show them, and have VoiceOver only read the visible views, they would need to toggle both flags at the same time in order for visibility and accessibility/VoiceOver to track together.

Comment: @DuncanC,@Starsky. Thanks for your reply.
I am working on a message detail screen, In that user can have more than 50+ messages, table gets scrolled to bottom to view the last message. While voiceover first thing is it scroll table to top, then start reading from the first cell to the last cell.
But iPhone default message app is only reading the 3-4 messages ( bases on visible in the screen when the table gets scrolled to the bottom )
I want to implement the same way.
For accessibility, I have implemented to read complete cell as a group, so I implemented in cellforrow of the table view.